# Spring integration recipient-list-router issue

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-jms, jms-topic, jmstemplate

I am using a recipient-list-router in my application to send message to different JMS outbound adapters as shown here:

```
queue -> recipient-list-router  -> queue1 -> JMS outbound adapter 1
                                -> queue2 -> JMS outbound adapter 2
```

I am facing two issues:

1. selector-expression runs initially only, not for each message forwarded
2. if any JMS broker is down then message is not getting sent to another JMS broker.

Following is the XML configuration:

```
<i:recipient-list-router input-channel="result-pack-output-channel" >
           <i:recipient channel="result-pack-output-channel-1" 
                          selector-expression="#{utils.isHourInInterval('LN')}"/>
            <i:recipient channel="result-pack-output-channel-2" 
                          selector-expression="#{utils.isHourInInterval('NY')}"/>
            <i:recipient channel="result-pack-output-channel-3" 
                        selector-expression="#{utils.isHourInInterval('HK')}" />
            <i:recipient channel="result-pack-output-channel-4" 
                        selector-expression="#{utils.isHourInInterval('ME')}"/> 
 </i:recipient-list-router>
```

Comment: Please show us some java code or the XML configuration of your implementation. Otherwise it´s hard to help you. Also, are you seeing any exceptions?

Comment: @Tobias: added the xml configuration

Comment: No exceptions @Tobias

Answer (score 0):

`#{...}` expressions are evaluated once, during context initialization. Here, you need runtime expressions. In runtime expressions you reference other beans with `@` - so...

```
selector-expression="@utils.isHourInInterval('LN')"
```

**EDIT**

I missed your second question - use `ignore-send-failures="true">`.

Comment: Please also mention `AbstractMessageRouter.ignoreSendFailures`. (I've spent too much time in gitter so lost my chance to answer ;-))

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russell. I did the change but not sure whether expression is working. tried to put log line in bean but not printing. Will update after checking in detail.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thanks for the efforts :)